# Apache 2.4 on MacOS suddenly wrong permissions

Tags: apache-2.4, mac-osx

Suddenly my local installation of Apache 2.4 on MacOS Yosemite stopped working.
The problem seems to be related with permissions, but I can't find a way out.

After several hours and reading several posts, the situation is now:

Error:

```
[authz_core:debug] [pid 35232] mod_authz_core.c(799): [client 127.0.0.1:55992] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[core:crit] (24)Too many open files: [client ::1:53498] AH00529: /Users/username/Sites/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/Users/username/Sites/' is executable
```

(I don't have such .htaccess file). Anyway, I enforced brutally 777 permission everywhere:

```
$ chmod -R a+rwx /Users/username
$ ls -l /Users/username
drwxrwxrwx  187 username  staff      6358 Dec 13 16:05 Sites
$ ls -l /Users/
drwxrwxrwx+ 174 username  staff  5916 Dec 13 16:39 username
```

My directive in httpd.conf is as follow:

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    #Require all granted - tried, doesn't matter
</Directory>
```

I can get rid of **AllowOverride**, but I do really need .htaccess AND anyway the problem with permission is still present for many images and resources in my virtual hosts.

As suggested by somebody, I changed apache user inside httpd.conf

```
#User _www
#Group _www
User username
Group staff
```

Still the same.

Comment: Changing permissions won't help with "Too many open files". Restart your computer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton actually that's the error showing already after restarting the computer

Comment: @MichaelHampton well, as you suggested I focused on "too many open files" problem. I checked with lsof and there where 351 open files for httpd. I disabled all my Vhost except one and now it seems stable. I still don't understand what could have been changed that lowered my limit, nor I understand how to raise it again...

Answer (score 0):

What are your hit counts/day? If they are high you could try changing your caching settings. It could be that you are keeping files opened in an attempt to improve your response times. How many virtual domains are you hosting? What is the (approx.) total file count for your vhosts? This seems like it could be a performance tuning problem...

Comment: it's just for local development, so hit count it's not an issue here. Apache is not starting! I have around 130 virtual hosts. What I believe is that probably apache is trying to check all folders on my Sites directory for .htaccess on starting. Number of folders can be then in the range of thousands. I don't understand what has changed in my configuration, because it worked until last week.